# A question about the generators of proper orthochronous Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra

In Special Relativity, we are introduced that any proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation can be given by
\begin{align}
L=e^{u\cdot K+\theta\cdot J}
\end{align}
where $u\cdot K=u_1K_1+u_2K_2+u_3K_3$ and $\theta\cdot J=\theta_1 J_1+\theta_2J_2+ \theta_3J_3$ $\ (K_i, J_i$ are the generators of the Lorentz group).

However, in some matereial of of reference, I found a result that every proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation can be expressed as
$$L=e^{u_iK_i+\theta_iJ_i}\ \ \text{for some }i. $$

I just wonder if this is true, and how can one deduce this formula ? Thanks.

Comment: It’s not “for some $i$”, it’s for $i$ summed over 1,2,3 according to the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: @Ghoster I mean, as I understand the statement of this proposition, then each transformation $L=e^{u_1K_1+u_2K_2+u_3K_3 +\theta_1J_1+ \theta_2J_2+ \theta_3J_3} $ can be expressed by a matrix $L=e^{v_1K_1+\psi_1J_1} $ or $e^{v_2K_2+\psi_2J_2} $ or $e^{v_3K_3+\psi_3J_3}$. You can check it [here](http://quantum.phys.unm.edu/523-14/LorentzGroup.pdf) at the equation (10.242).

Comment: You erroneously think that because you don’t understand that the Einstein summation convention is being used. There is an *implicit sum*.

Comment: This notation is first used in (10.234) and was surely explained earlier. So I don’t see how you made it all the way to (10.242) before getting confused.

Comment: This notation is usually encountered first in Newtonian mechanics with equations like $L_i=I_{ij}\omega_j$. It isn’t just a relativistic thing. Physicists use it whenever they are dealing with indexed quantities.

Comment: @Ghoster I also found a result that any proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation  has an unique decomposition as a product of a spatial rotation $R$ followed by a pure boost $B$, which means $L=BR$. The pure boost is given by $B=e^{u_iK_i}$ and the rotation is $R=e^{\theta_i J_i}$, then 
\begin{align}
L=BR=e^{u_iK_i}e^{\theta_i J_i}=e^{u_iK_i+\theta_iJ_i}.
\end{align}
You can check it [here](https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/1431989/download?download_frd=1&verifier=nE22rvVFwLBXnf9QcU57uOflz7EhlnwH1hmaz93Y) at Proposition II.1.

Comment: The Einstein summation convention is being used there as well.

Comment: Your final equality is incorrect. In general $e^Ae^B\ne e^{A+B}$ when $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

Comment: You can also write the unique decomposition $L=RB$, but the rotation and the boost won’t be the same as in $L=BR$. So don’t read too much into the uniqueness.

Comment: Do you know about Einstein summation convention. If not, go read about that first.